# Usage of demonstrative pronouns in “celle de ceux”

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, pronoms-relatifs, démonstratifs

> Une histoire troublante, intimement liée à celle de ceux qui les ont habités.

I would like an explanation of the “celle de ceux” part. 
Isn't *celle* the demonstrative pronoun in this case? 
And *ceux-ci* and *ceux-là* are too but here *ceux* is without the proper ending so does that mean that *ceux qui* is a relative pronoun?

Comment: To make the sense clear, an English translation (somewhat bad and to literal) of the sentence would be: a puzzling story, linked to that of those who inhabited them

Comment: To be noted also : in most contexts, people avoid to use so many pronouns to remain clear, because such sentences would often confuse interlocutors and would sometimes need repetition or clarification. A less sophisticated way to reformulate your initial sentence would be *Une histoire troublante, intimement liée à celle de ses habitants.*

Comment: I agree with @RomainVALERI ‘s rewrite completely, because as the sentence stands, I can’t make sense of the plural “LES” does it refer to UNE histoire (singular, so I’d say “no”) … or to “Celle” (again singular, so again I’d say “no”) … or to “ceux” (plural, yes, but having an object refer to a subject seems weird to me). Should “celle” perhaps be plural here… “celleS de ceux,” with “LES” referring to “celleS”? (also, is it possible that “habité” should be replaced by “vecu” in the French version?... One “lives/endures” a story/stories, but can one “live at/inhabit” a story/stories?) Help,svp!

Comment: @PapaPoule merci for breaking it down so beautifully but the sentence remains the same. I read it in a teen magazine. Is it possible its a cooler way of saying things? Sorry I am just as lost.

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t mean to imply that you had mis-transcribed the sentence or that you should edit it in your question! (I’m not even sure that my two points of confusion are valid, so maybe it doesn’t need editing at all). Hopefully you’ll get an answer that straightens it all out for the both of us!

Comment: Celle refers to l'histoire de ceux qui ... It is a singular because it points to one story shared by all these people

Comment: I found an instance of the source material where the preceding sentence is "[...]les _lieux_ ont une histoire." That last word is overly emphasized and as was shown this is quite convoluted; it also included a past participle with no plural word to match(had it been feminine someone could guess it was about "maisons", as here someone can guess "lieux".) Then it becomes about which of the past ppl of vivre or habiter matches maison/lieu the best but it's not your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're both *pronoms démonstratifs*, *celle* refers to *une histoire* while *ceux* refers to *(les gens / implied) qui les ont habités*